# How change input language in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

When the user focus to text field I want to check if the active input language is English the application should change it automatically to Arabic.
I tried

```
InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();
```

But it return default language not active language.

Comment: Could you put your code ?

Comment: " it return default language "  - `getInstance` does not return a language. See [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/im/InputContext.html#getInstance()) :  "Returns a new InputContext instance."